# Does my DLink DNS-323 need to reside on a "192.168.0.0/24" subnet?

Tags: nas

I've installed two brand new 2-tib drives in the DLink and plugged it in to my network.  My router is configured as a DHCP server using an alternate subnet (10.10.0.0/24) and I added MAC address of the device to a static list (such that when MAC address X requests an address it will always get Y); however it doesn't show up in the router's DHCP client table, nor the arp table (looking for MAC here).

1. Do I need to use the custom software to administer this device?
2. Do I need to use a "192.168.0.0/24" network in order for this device to work (asking because it states that if DHCP isn't detected, it will default to an address in that range; and my network is not in that range).

Comment: Are you using DHCP? Do you have your router configured as a DHCP server? Where is it not showing up?

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: There is a [related question](http://superuser.com/questions/467986/is-it-possible-to-change-your-local-ip-to-something-other-than-192-168-x-x) where I noted that while it may be possible to modify the IP address in the router, it could have unforeseen side-effects like this. You need to check the manual for the drives to see if they can work on `10.0.0`.

Comment: Make sure the DNS-323 is getting link light on its connection to the router. Then reboot it. It should attempt DHCP by default. If all else fails, either use Easy Search (or configure a computer to connect to the DNS-323 on its default IP address) to configure the DNS-323 for the correct IP address.

Comment: I've scoured the manuals and it states only that if DHCP is not enabled it will use 192.168.0.32 which led me to my belief that there is some hard-coded awesomeness in its networking stack.  The link light is coming on, and when I port scan my network it flashes, so the NIC itself is working to a degree.

Answer (score 0):

If it is anything like an older Dlink NAS I had, the answer is that it comes pre set to a static ip... I think 192.168.0.100 (but I forget now).

Simply try to match the subnet for it and enable DHCP client.

Comment: (FYI, I just remember the static IP issue... Just googled and put the top result here which showed 192.168.0.10)

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone here works for D-Link and knows the 323's hardware/software requirements, no one (here) is going to know the answer to your question - Whether the 323 must reside on a 192.168.0/24 network.

Page 22 of the 323's [manual](ftp://ftp.dlink.es/Media%20Center/DNS-323/Manual/DNS-323_manual.pdf) doesn't provide any specific (or helpful) guidance other than saying it can use a static IP or use DHCP.

The simplest approach to answer your question would be to reconfigure your router to serve an address on 192.168.0/24 and see if things start working.

Barring that, since your router ARP log doesn't show a DHCP REQ (request) from the 323, there may be something else going on - either with your router or with the 323.  Another thing to try would be to place an analyzer/Sniffer (like Wireshark) in between the 323 and the router. If you see DHCP REQ's coming from the 323, you know the issue is with the router. Otherwise, if you don't see requests, you know the problem is with the 323.

Remember that if you're in a switched environment, you will only see the DHCP request broadcast on the initial broadcast/flood and not DHCP reply from the router (assuming you're not port mirroring or using a passive splice, etc.)

Comment: *> Unless someone here works for D-Link and knows the 323's hardware/software requirements, no one (here) is going to know the answer to your question - Whether the 323 must reside on a 192.168.0/24 network.*   Actually, if anything is in question, it is the drives, not the router.